# How do I pass a nested list of integers to Google's command line flags?

Tags: python, command-line, parameter-passing, tensorflow, gflags

How do I pass a nested list of integers to [`gflags`](https://github.com/gflags/python-gflags)? I can get my code working with something like

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('network_nodes', [784, [5, 5, 32], [5, 5, 64], 1200, 10], 'The network structure')
```

But attempting to use this at the command line with something like

```
python test.py --network_nodes=[784, 100, 10]
```

results (not surprisingly) in an error:

> `test.py: error: argument --network_nodes: invalid int value: '[784, 100, 10]'`

How do I pass a nested list of integers to `gflags` (or TensofFlow's `tf.app.flags`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation: https://github.com/gflags/python-gflags/blob/master/gflags.py

```
DEFINE_list: Takes a comma-separated list of strings on the commandline.
         Stores them in a python list object.
```

So you would have to pass it as a list of string `--network_nodes=784,100,10` and then convert the strings to floats.

Comment: What about "nested" (see question)?

Comment: for nested I would suggest to just pass a string and then `eval` the string in python.

Comment: Any idea where the documentation for this has gone? I'm having trouble finding any (e.g, to set defaults, valid values, short names, required flags). The link above is dead.